# Need to find the employee who has not checkedin today but has checkout

Tags: sql

[image]

I have added the screenshots of the employee who forget to checkin on 1st but has checkedout on the same day. I tried this query

```
select t.*
      from M_AttendanceResult t outer apply
           (select count(t2.checkintime) as cnt
            from M_AttendanceResult t2
            where t2.AccountID = t.AccountID and
                  coalesce(t2.checkintime, t2.checkouttime) <= coalesce(t.checkintime, t.checkouttime)
                 -- and CheckOutTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-3,120) and convert(varchar(10),getdate()+1,120)
           ) ins outer apply
           (select count(t2.checkouttime) as cnt
            from M_AttendanceResult t2
            where t2.AccountID = t.AccountID and
                  coalesce(t2.checkouttime, t2.checkintime) <= coalesce(t.checkouttime, t.checkintime)
                  and CheckOutTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-3,120) and convert(varchar(10),getdate()+1,120)
           ) outs
where t.checkouttime is not null and outs.cnt > ins.cnt
```

But it is giving me blank output. I am using mssql2008

I also tried this

```
select * from M_AttendanceResult
where 
 CheckOutTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-3,120) and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
and not exists
(select CheckInTime from M_AttendanceResult
where CheckInTime is not null
and CheckInTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-3,120) and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120))
```

But still blank output.

Comment: please add DDL,expected result,current result

Comment: expected result should be the employee I highlighted, and currently I am getting blank result

Comment: What if a user checks in a few minutes befor midnight, and checks out a few minutes after midnight?

Comment: It will not happen because there will be no 1 working at night in my scenario

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if there are no other row with same date as checkin.

```
select * from tablename t1
where t1.checkouttime is not null
  and not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where date(t2.checkindate) = date(t1.checkoutdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this Query:

```
SELECT t.* from M_AttendanceResult t 
          WHERE t.AccountID IN 
          (SELECT AccountID from M_AttendanceResult 
               WHERE CAST(CheckInTime AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: I have modified the query. Please try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

select ma.AccountName,m.AccountID,ma.AccountIndex,CheckInTime,CheckOutTime,ShiftID,
DepartmentAccountID from M_AttendanceResult as m
      join M_Account as ma
      on m.AccountID=ma.AccountID
            where (CheckInTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) and         convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
      or 
     CheckOutTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) and          convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120))
     and CheckInTime is null
    and not exists
        ( select * from M_AttendanceResult as mm
          where CheckInTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,120) and       convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
          and mm.AccountID=m.AccountID)

Comment: I got the answers guys thanks for your help appreciated!!